# How to use cmake to install config file in cross-platform project

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I'm developing a system which runs on both Windows and Linux. I use cmake to build and install the system. But now, I met a problem with configuration file. On Linux, I can put the configuration file in /etc (by convention) and use absolute path to access it in the code. On windows, the config file should be in the install folder of this project. I tried to install it on Linux using following script.

```
install(
  FILES config/msp.json
  DESTINATION etc
  COMPONENT controller
)
```

But I don't know if it works on Windows and how I refer to the path in code.
Is there any convention to do this?

Comment: "But I don't know if it works on Windows" - Why do you think that Windows deny to install something into `etc/` subfolder? In any case, you could easily try that. "how I refer to the path in code" - You could refer to the config file like to any other file shipped with your project. E.g. by using path of the file **relative** to the path of the executable. Or you may maintain some environment variable which point to the file.